# Superfish sf-js-enabled seems to be not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, superfish

I tried to do a dropdown menu using Superfish. However, the drop down doesn't seems to be working. All scrips and link are directed to the js/css file. I have also done the script that needed to ready the function. But it doesn't seems to work. *note* I'm doing this on static html.

I have tried to change the source file name to check whether is it source issue, but doesn't seems to be, as I still can take in my main.css but not the superfish.css or .js file. I have also did comparison with some other website that uses superfish, seems to be the same.

```
    <link href="http://localhost:8383/1004Project/public_html/css/superfish.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="http://localhost:8383/1004Project/public_html/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8383/1004Project/public_html/js/superfish.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8383/1004Project/public_html/js/hoverIntent.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
        });
    </script>
```

```
<nav id="primary-menu">
                            <ul class="sf-js-enabled">
                                <li><a href="ProjectStories.html"><div>Project's Stories</div></a></li>
                                <li><a href="Menus.html"><div>Menus</div></a></li>
                                <li><a href="Promotions.html"><div>Promotions</div></a></li>
                                <li><a href="CelebrationTips.html"><div>Celebration Tips</div></a></li>
                                <li class="sub-menu">
                                    <a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">
                                        <div>Help</div>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul style="display: none;">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="FAQ.html"><div>FAQ</div></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="Feedback.html"><div>Feedback</div></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="ContactUs.html"><div>Contact Us</div></a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
```

I'm hoping the dropdown menu to work. It doesn't even have the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an working sample example 
Your code need some css changes too so i referred some basic example from 
 [here](https://superfish.joelbirch.design/examples/)
Also make sure all the scripts are loading properly and you are not having any errors in browser console too regarding the scripts.

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/superfish/1.7.10/css/superfish.min.css" media="screen">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/superfish/1.7.10/js/superfish.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<div id="sample1" class="clearfix">
    <ul id="sample-menu-1" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-arrows" style="touch-action: pan-y;">
        <li class="current"><a href="#a" class="sf-with-ul">menu item</a>
            <ul style="display: none;">
                <li><a href="#aa">menu item</a></li>
                <li class="current"><a href="#ab" class="sf-with-ul">menu item</a>
                    <ul style="display: none;">
                        <li class="current"><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#aba">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#abb">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#abc">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#abd">menu item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">menu item</a>
                    <ul style="display: none;">
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">menu item</a>
                    <ul style="display: none;">
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">menu item</a>
            <ul style="display: none;">
                <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">menu item</a>
                    <ul style="display: none;">
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">menu item</a>
                    <ul style="display: none;">
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">menu item</a>
                    <ul style="display: none;">
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">menu item</a>
                    <ul style="display: none;">
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">menu item</a>
                    <ul style="display: none;">
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help! I realize my error is that I did not put in sf-menu in my ul. However, this can only be done if I uses your link and script. Do you have any idea how to change the background colour? But thanks for the help!

Comment: To change background color you need to override the classes like these 
.sf-menu ul li {
    background: #86c182;
}
.sf-menu li {
    background: #5679da;
}
you can find them easily by inspecting them in browser.

Comment: If it is only working with the links and scripts i have shared then you are not using the correct path to your resources

Comment: I placed those css and js files in the same file as my main.css file, main.js file. I can access those, I placed the same file path, so it should be working right? I'm not sure. As I'm fairly new to html. Noted on the background change, will do that. I don't really like the arrow at the side of my help.

Comment: how you are running your page / application are you  using any server

Comment: I'm using xampp apache.

Comment: ok ,  you can use relative path like this <script src="./js/superfish.js"></script> 
in the above use case  my htdocs folder having file named index.html and a folder named js which having superfish.js

Comment: With relative path, i could work, i could use my main.css to overwrite the css, which it seems like i personally create the css instead. However, I'm back to no longer have dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure the document ready is placed after your html body.

if u place in top of body, it wont work because the dom element is not created yet.

Comment: I have tried to place it in the body. However, it still doesn't work.